# Android Facebook 3.5 sharing ugly login issues

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the facebook 3.5 api to achieve some simple text sharing for my app's users in android. I do have it working, but the login process is a bit unstable and ugly.

I have the sharing isolated to a single activity (since this is a hack to cover the fact that facebook does not allow us to share text (even user edited) directly to their app. Because of this the facebook login frequently occurs right before sending text (acceptable) but also requests the user confirm permission requests twice (once for read, once for write) and sometimes after clicking yes on both, the login session is lost and an original user login is requested again (this is pretty ugly!).

Here is the code I am using below:

from onCreate():

```
        mSession = Session.getActiveSession();
    if(mSession!=null){
        if(!mSession.isOpened()){
            mSession.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(FBShareActivity.this).setCallback(mStatusCallback));
            Session.setActiveSession(mSession);
        }
    }else {
        mSession = new Session(FBShareActivity.this);
        mSession.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(FBShareActivity.this).setCallback(mStatusCallback));
        Session.setActiveSession(mSession);
    }
```

from my wall post code:

```
        if(mSession!=null) {

        // Check for publish permissions    
        List<String> permissions = mSession.getPermissions();
        if (!isSubsetOf(SHARE_TEXT_PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                    .NewPermissionsRequest(this, SHARE_TEXT_PERMISSIONS);
            mSession.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
            return;
        }

        Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        postParams.putString("name", book.getTitle());
        if(msgTitle!=null&&msgTitle.length()>0)
            postParams.putString("caption", msgTitle);
        postParams.putString("message", quote);
        if(mReceivedUri!=null&&mReceivedUri.toString().length()>0) {
            //TODO: Actually we need to put the image data in here!!
            byte[] data = null;

            Log.e(TAG, "[shareBookQuote] image uri = "+mReceivedUri.toString());

            Bitmap bi;
            try {
                bi = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), mReceivedUri);

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                data = baos.toByteArray();

                postParams.putByteArray("photo", data);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to locate image file to share", e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load image file to share", e);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load image file to share", e);
            }

        }

        Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                if(response!=null) {
                    String postId = null;
                    GraphObject gObj = response.getGraphObject();
                    if(gObj!=null){
                        JSONObject graphResponse = gObj.getInnerJSONObject();

                        try {
                            postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.i(TAG,
                                "JSON error "+ e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                    if (error != null) {
                        String errorTitle = getString(R.string.fb_error_title);
                        String errorMessage = error.getErrorMessage();
                        int errorCode = error.getErrorCode();

                        if(errorCode==100) {
                            //Tried to send empty message
                            errorMessage = getString(R.string.fb_error_no_message);
                            showFragmentMessage(errorTitle, errorMessage);
                        } else {
                            //Other error, just report it to the user
                            showFragmentMessage(errorTitle, errorMessage);
                        }
                        //Make this an error dialog instead of a toast!!

                    } else {

                        returnToApp(); //My own fxn for returning to the app
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        if(mReceivedUri==null) {
            Request request = new Request(mSession, "me/feed", postParams, 
                                  HttpMethod.POST, callback);

            RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
            task.execute();
        } else {
            Request request = new Request(mSession, "me/photos", postParams, 
                    HttpMethod.POST, callback);

            RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
            task.execute();
        }

    }
```

additionally:

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Though this code does actually work, it does seem to have problems with the above stated problems of multiple logins and excessive user permission requests. Is there something I am doing wrong, or is this how the facebook API is supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I was using the wrong permission name when requesting permissions from facebook:

```
private static final List<String> SHARE_TEXT_PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
```

The correct permissions were:

```
private static final List<String> SHARE_TEXT_PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_stream");
```

Even though the publish_actions did indeed pull the right permissions, when I checked to see that I had the right permissions, I always had publish_stream. Switching to requesting publish_stream directly solved this.